# Android - Error while writing file to external storage

Tags: android

I was trying to create a simple .txt file in external storage, but I got nullPointerException, here is the code and error log, I'm not sure what I did wrong:

**MainActivity:**

```
package com.externalstoragedemo;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    File dir;
    File file;
    String Text = "File has been created!";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(isExternalStorageReadable() && isExternalStorageWriteable()){
            dir = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Documents");
            dir.mkdirs();

            file = new File(dir, "Simple.txt");
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try{
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(Text.getBytes());
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(fos != null){
                try {
                    fos.close();
                    textView.setText(Text);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isExternalStorageReadable(){
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state))
        {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isExternalStorageWriteable(){
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

**LayoutFile:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.externalstoragedemo.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**ErrorLOG:**

> 08-26 20:54:32.161 24298-24298/com.externalstoragedemo
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                            Process: com.externalstoragedemo, PID: 24298
>                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.externalstoragedemo/com.externalstoragedemo.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2174)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5151)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
>                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:120)
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:155)
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:31)
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:55)
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:205)
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
>                                                                                at com.externalstoragedemo.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:14)
>                                                                                at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
>                                                                                at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
>                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2165)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5151) 
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868) 
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684) 
>                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Pretty sure that same error would happen with just `TextView.setText("hello")`... You can't use findViewById outside of a method or before calling SetContentView

Answer (score 0):

Pass this to the inside of the onCreate method:

```
TextView textview;
...
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
...
```

Comment: Thank you man, it was a mistake which led to app crash. But still somehow I my file haven't been created. Any suggestions? Thank you again.

Comment: @SteveYo, that is a different question. Ask a different question

Comment: You should use log calls or use the debugger to see what is sequence of events of whats happening. Only by looking at the code I can't tell you what is wrong.